# Need help with this search format

Tags: support, search

> [angular] or [javascript] or [json] or [npm] or [regex] or [rxjs] or
>   [typescript] and -[reactjs]

The above gets me everything.
I want to ensure that only items tagged

> [angular] or [javascript] or [json] or [npm] or [regex] or [rxjs] or
>   [typescript]

are returned.

When I search I'm seeing all sorts of posts unrelated to what I'm looking for.

Updated:

> [angular] or [javascript] or [json] or [npm] or [regex] or [rxjs] or [typescript] -[reactjs] -[react-native] -[react-redux] -[react-router] -[azure-active-directory] -[react-native-android] -[vue.js] -[vuejs2]

Having multiple - items does not work as I expected. How can I group it so it contains all of the **OR** conditions and has an **AND**

> cond1 or cond2 or cond3 or cond4 or cond5 etc...
>    AND
>   (-[reactjs] -[react-native] -[react-redux] -[react-router]
>   -[azure-active-directory] -[react-native-android] -[vue.js] -[vuejs2])

Comment: `[angular] or [javascript] or [json] or [npm] or [regex] or [rxjs] or [typescript] -[reactjs]` it helps?

Comment: @Arulkumar That helps with restriction of 1 topic, which does help but.

Comment: How do I restrict on many? See updated question.

Comment: [tags] or [more-tags] or [other-tags] -[not-these-tags] and -[less-tags] and -[no-tags]